# Error when installing Pandas in AWS

Tags: gcc, amazon-web-services, pandas

I am following the below steps to install pandas in AWS micro instance (he platform is Amazon Linux). I SSH to the AWS instance and run the below commands to install the dependencies.

```
$sudo yum install gcc
$sudo yum install gcc-c++
$ sudo pip install numpy
$ sudo yum install python-devel
$ sudo yum install pytz
```

I get the error as below

```
    pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h:49:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘KHASH_MAP_INIT_STR’

 KHASH_MAP_INIT_STR(strbox, kh_pyobject_t)

 ^

{standard input}: Assembler messages:

{standard input}:107066: Warning: end of file not at end of a line; newline inserted

{standard input}:107394: Error: number of operands mismatch for `mov'

{standard input}: Error: open CFI at the end of file; missing .cfi_endproc directive

gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)

Please submit a full bug report,

with preprocessed source if appropriate.

See <http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla> for instructions.

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 4

----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-YJi1l7/pandas/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-9dXSKp-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-YJi1l7/pandas
```

Comment: What AMI are you using? It is very crutial information. I run pandas in amazon on the "Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS (HVM), SSD Volume Type" just fine.

Comment: the platform is Amazon Linux

aws-elasticbeanstalk-amzn-2015.03.0.x86_64-python27-pv

it is a micro instance

Comment: I am having the same problem. Did you find any solution @GeraldVarghese?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most likely running out of memory. Try making a swap file - it worked for me:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1024 count=524288
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
sudo pip install pandas
```

Comment: If you think you will need the extra juice later too, you can bump up instance size under Configuration > Instances.